# Use regex to extract table names from SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, parsing

I need an opinion about parsing SQL (Oracle) with regex.

There are pretty entertaining posts in StackOverflow that explain that regex over HTML or XML is hopeless ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)).

Is that the case with SQL as well? And even if the answer is no, is the specific problem below solvable with regex? Last fallback, what else would work?

Requirement: Verify that the table names in arbitrary SQL are enclosed in square brackets (should be "[name]").

Constraint: Use ksh/bash, i.e. grep|sed|awk.

For the SQL below the script should flag bad_table as not matching (should have been [bad_table]). Should work on arbitrary SQL, here a simpler one without joins.

```
SELECT id
FROM [order]
WHERE id IN (SELECT oid
             FROM [audit] a, bad_table d, (SELECT xid FROM [t1]) r
             WHERE a.data = r.data and a.data = d.data)
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: For the specific problem of extracting table names from SQL with no comments, the problem is probably solvable.

Comment: "*Is that the case with SQL as well?*" Yes, because SQL allows arbitrarily nested constructs (e.g. with `(` `)`).

Comment: How would you want to handle common table expressions?  E.g., `WITH cte AS ( SELECT ... ) SELECT ... FROM cte`?  In this case `cte` is not an object in your database, but I think you'll be hard-pressed to keep your script from thinking it is a table.  I won't say your requirements are impossible, but they're definitely impractical.

Comment: This is tagged with Oracle, square brackets is a SQL Server (and possibly other databases) thing and is not allowed in Oracle.

Comment: Another consideration is unaliased table names, e.g. instead of say `select a.id from [audit] a` you might have `select audit.id from [audit]`, so should the plain `audit` table reference in the select list (or anywhere else in the query) be flagged too?

Comment: Do I dare ask why you need to do this?  Maybe there is a more straightforward way to do what you want (eg, you can parse SQL in Oracle )

Comment: @tbone & Brian - I should have mentioned from the beginning why such processing. The SQL files are input to a tool that processes them in a specific way. That tool requires tables in this specific format. At the end of the processing chain the schema is created in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I have done more reading and it is clear now that the task is not possible with regex. The theory says that - SQL is non-regular language and regex is not up to this task. A SQL parser is required.

That being said, a compromise has been reached as something had to be done at work: use a collection of regular expressions (2 as of now) that work on the ~300 SQL files that need processing as of today. Admit that one day someone will come up with a SQL that would fail. Add for that occasion a comment in the code that explains why a tweak is needed to cover that corner case and, best, use a SQL parser...

Many thanks to everyone who contributed.